# Customizing build path for Maven based projects in NetBeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, ant, ivy

I'm wondering if it is possible (and how if yes) to customize Maven projects build path.

Example: we are developing modules for a huge server. All the core build process is based on Ant and Ivy (custom ivy settings for resolving internal proprietary dependencies). But we are developing modules which are also quite big using Maven because its just much more comfortable for us. Then using Ants Maven plugin building all the stuff together - works like a charm.

But this Ant(Ivy)+ Maven combo makes it impossible for me to use NetBeans. I love them, I want to use them but unfortunatelly NetBeans don't allow me to customize the build path when the project is based on pom.xml.

It would be great just to have the possibility to add JAR files next to the dependencies resolved by Maven (like in basic Java Application ant based project. Messing with pom is not the way and I don't need exactly resolving ivy dependencies. Only for editor use.

The whole build process is working -> so `mvn install` resolves ivy dependencies during the build but NetBeans dont see them.

Idea and Eclipse are able to that, but would love to see it happen in NetBeans too.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.... Are you by any chance using Maven to call an ANT build (via ant plugin), which in turn is using ivy for dependency management? If so my advice is to use one tech or the other (ANT+ivy or Maven). Publish everything to a Maven repository for sharing. This enables each project to chose the build technology that suits them and you're more likely to have happier IDEs.

Comment: You are right, that is the way it works. But I can't change that. That would be way too much effort and the other thing is. Problem is that everyona else is using eclipse or idea and are satisfied. I joined the team in a later stage and just can't get used to Eclipse.